# GWT Error: not being able to import com.google.gwt.view.client.ListViewAdapter

Tags: gwt

I am not being able to import com.google.gwt.view.client.ListViewAdapter;. I have GWT 2.1 and it is giving the error The import com.google.gwt.view.client.ListViewAdapter
cannot be resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ListViewAdapter has been replaced by ListDataProvider in 2.1